# How to set Alternative Characters Key in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 18.04

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. Our language need to use **Alternative Characters Key** in "Typing". I can use this option in Ubuntu 16.04 and didn't find in Ubuntu version 18.04. How do I set this in Ubuntu 18.04?

[image]

Updated!...............

The Following picture is our keyboard layout. In Ubuntu version 16.04, Firstly I installed our keyboard and then go to Keyboard >> Typing >> and set Right Alt for Alternative Character Key.

In the following picture, I pointed to two arrows with different colors to words. Red Arrow pointed word is Main Word. If I want to type Blue Arrow pointed word, I need press the Right Alt and then press "P". So It will work. Currently I am facing the problem in 18.04 for type some of these Characters which was use by pressing Alternative Character Key in 16.04. Please solve my problem. Thank you.

[Our Keyboard Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwyCS.png)

Comment: The Alternative Character Key is usually labeled 'AltGr' right to the space bar. Do you have this key? Or is it just dead in 18.04? Can you link to a picture of your keyboard layout and describe your issue a little more?

Comment: Hi @emk2203. Thank you for your reply. My laptop keyboard has 'AltGr' key. But I mean that 16.04 keyboard setting >> Typing >> Alternative Character Key option do not appeared in Ubuntu version 18.04. So I would like to use this option but did not find in 18.04. Please check the following link for picture. Thank you and sorry for my poor english.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSlrm.png

Comment: If you have the 'AltGr' key, can you use for entering the special characters you need? Could you give an example what you want to type? Maybe it is easier then.

Comment: @emk2203 I updated my post above and attached our Keyboard Layout picture.

Comment: I think what @emk2203 means is that normally it should just work, or do you want to change it to some other key? Or maybe you need to select a different keyboard layout in the settings?

Answer (score 6):

You need to install `gnome-tweaks` and go to the menuitem 'keyboard & mouse'. From there, the button 'extended options' lets you reassign the key. In your case, you **don't** have an <kbd>AltGr</kbd>, it is a right <kbd>Alt</kbd>. Please set your preferences accordingly. You want to have the 3rd level assigned to your right <kbd>Alt</kbd> and maybe the 4th level to <kbd>Shift</kbd> right <kbd>Alt</kbd> if I get your intentions right.

The keyboard layout picture was really helpful to clear up the confusion.

Comment: Does it mean I have to install the gnome-tweaks package in order to use international keyboards? Surely there has to be an easier way?

Answer (score 4):

For many layouts, you'll need to set Gnome Tweaks `Compose Key` to `Right Super`(see  pic below). Youĺl need to click on whatever it shows instead of "Right Super" to select this.

[image]
non
AltGr is actually Right Super in many layouts.

Once you select this you can use "English(US,int., with dead keys)" layout which is great for writing in English *and* Spanish without need to change the layout (this or similar could be useful for other international Latin-based languages with accents,  tilde or similar special chars). For Spanish in particular, it allows one to type an `ñ` by just typing `AltGr`+`n` while using an USA keyboard which is the most practical/ organized qwerty layout if you are using more than just alphabetical symbols, i.e {}][;?<,./... as it is not filled with `ñ`, `ç` or similar...

Answer (score 1):

Building on the two answers above, I mapped a 3rd level (Typically <kbd>AltGr</kbd>) to <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> by installing `gonme-tweeks` and selecting:

> Keyboard & Mouse -> Additional Layout Options -> Key to choose 3rd level -> Left Alt

[image: Gnome tweeks menus]