# How do I change the alternate character key on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: keyboard, 18.04, gnome-tweak-tool

I cant find were to change the alternate character key on Ubuntu 18.04. other posts [How to set Alternative Characters Key in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030248/how-to-set-alternative-characters-key-in-ubuntu-18-04) suggested gnome-teaks but i could not figure it out.
I am doing this so i can write brackets with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>, <kbd>8</kbd>, <kbd>9</kbd>, or <kbd>0</kbd> and a different post suggested changing the alternate character key but its not there on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: *System parameter* -> *Keyboard* -> *Shortcuts*

Comment: its not listed there

Comment: if it was i would'nt ask